# Q# ResourcesEstimator for quantum chemistry of 1000+ qubit systems

Tags: q#

*This is a q# question about resource estimation on quantum chemistry problems*

In the [docomentation for ResourcesEstimator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/machines/resources-estimator), it states that `...by executing the quantum operation without actually simulating the state of a quantum computer; for this reason, it can estimate resources for Q# operations that use thousands of qubits.`

I am wondering how we can perform Quantum Chemistry simulation resource estimation on thousands of qubits. Although a quantum circuit of thousands of qubits can be an input to ResourcesEstimator, it is not clear to me how to generate the quantum circuit using the conventional workflow as described in [this documentation on end-to-end with NWChem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/libraries/chemistry/samples/end-to-end#producing-and-consuming-broombridge-output-from-nwchem).

As far as I understand, the .nw file suggests generating the molecular electron-integrals which outputs to a BroomBridge .yaml file which loads to the GetGatecount and similar resource estimators. However, in a 1000+ qubit chemistry simulation, just the generation of the yaml file would take days on a beefy computer and the filesize would be giga or terabytes in size.

My question is; can we do this resource estimation without explicitly calculating the Hamiltonian matrix elements? If not, how do you propose doing these large-scale resource estimations 'up to thousands of qubits'?

Thanks for your help! [q#]

Answer (score 1):

It would be more accurate to say "it can estimate resources for Q# operations that use thousands of qubits, *if the classical part of the code can be executed in a reasonable time*".

QDK resource estimator is basically a special simulator which still "executes" the Q# program it gets. Unlike the full state or Toffoli simulators, though, it does not simulate the effect of the gates and measurements on the state of the quantum systems - instead it increments certain counters that track the metrics produced by resource estimator. For example, if you use a T gate, it will increment the counter of T gates but will not touch the counter of Pauli gates or CNOTs.

This means that the resource estimator can run much larger programs than the other simulators (the main restriction on full state simulator comes from the need to update the full state of the system, which grows larger than the available memory around 30-40 qubits). But it still needs to be able to run the program, going through all the gates and all the classical computations involved, even if going through the gates is much more lightweight than on a full state simulator.